# Integrating PanoramaGl in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, panoramas, 360-panorama-viewer

I am creating a 360 degree view and for that I am using **panoramagl-android** library. But for integrating all the steps are for Eclipse, there is no guide for android studio. The Link for library is below.
[Click Here](https://github.com/zarelaky/panoramagl-android/tree/master/PanoramaGL)

I am not able to understand the first two steps of section 4.2 in library read me file(Link Provided). 
Any help is appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using someone fork on google project. 
        Here is how you can do in studio 
        a. 
    Download the jar from  source code from repository
        You should use the following library. 
        https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/wikis/UserGuide.wiki

```
    you can download the lib file and in gradle build you can add libs into your sourcesets. 

     android {
     sourceSets {
            main {
     jniLibs.srcDirs=['libs']
    }
    }
```